# Unable to get keras flow_from_directory to work with .gif data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to build an Image classifier with keras and tensorflow. However currently `flow_from_directory` does not see my images due to them being in .gif format (I checked this with .jpg and it works here). How can I fix this?

This old [github page](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3946) claims that I should be able to put .gif on my `white_list_formats` in the keras/preprocessing/image.py file. But after opening it there seems to be no `white_list_formats` in my version of image.py. Did keras change anything here?

I'm on Windows using anaconda3 distribution in case that matters.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The github post you are referring to was posted for keras version 1.1.0. In the latest version they have removed that variable.

In the latest version of Keras, below formats are only supported.

**PNG, JPG, BMP, PPM, TIF**

Please refer to the [this](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) for documentation.

If you still want to try and edit white_list_format, please install keras 1.1.0 and try it.